# I have a C++ function that compiles in Dev C++ but not in G++

Tags: c++, linked-list

My main function calls out the remove function in the linkedlist

```
 case 7:
    input >> argument;
    cout << "Attempting to remove " << argument << endl;
    if(myList.remove(argument))
    {
        cout << "Successfully removed the element from the list\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not remove the element from the list\n";
    }
    break;
```

And my structure looks like this as well as my function calls

```
#ifndef LL_H
#define LL_H

// include this library to use NULL, otherwise use nullptr instead
#include <cstddef>

// include iostream so anything that includes this file can use cout
#include <iostream>

// Struct which will be the building block of our list
struct node{
    int val;
    node* next;
    node* prev;
};

// Linked list class definition
class LL{
public:
    LL();
    void prepend(int);
    void append(int);
    void remove(int);
    bool removeFront();
    bool removeBack();
    node* search(int);
    void print();
    void deleteList();
private:
    node* head;
};

#endif
```

With mycpp file looking like this

```
    #include "ll.h"
    LL::LL()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
    void LL::remove(int num){
```

This function searches for a node with num as its value, if found, it is deleted from the list

```
        node* second = head;
        node* first = head->next;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (head->val == num)
        {
            node* temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }   


        while (first&&first->val != num)
        {
            second = first;
            first = first->next;
        }
        if (first)
        {
            second->next = first->next;
            delete first;
        }

    }
```

The error is something about not being able to convert `myList` `remove` argument from `void` to `BOOL` but what am I calling out that thinks a `BOOL` function? I'm not passing `true` or `false` values back.

Comment: What is the exact error message, and which line is it pointing to?

Comment: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:66:29: error: could not convert 'myList.LL::remove(argument)" from 'void" to 'bool'
If (mylist.remove(argument))

Comment: Seriously, you have a C++ program on which you use C++ compiler and you thought the best language tag to choose was C - and C only?

Comment: It is tagged at C++ and linkedlist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `remove` is declared as a `void` function, and it doesn't return a value. So you can't use it in an `if()` statement, because it doesn't return a value that can be converted to boolean and tested.

Take out the `if()` around the call to `myList.remove(argument)`:

```
case 7:
    input >> argument;
    cout << "Attempting to remove " << argument << endl;
    myList.remove(argument);
    break;
```

Since the function doesn't return a value, you can't report whether it was successful. If you really need to do that, you have to change the definition of the function so it returns a boolean.

Comment: Geez, I take out that if statement then G++ really blows up

main.cpp undefined reference to LL:LL()
main.cpp undefined reference to LL:prepend(int)'
main.cpp undefined reference to LL:append(int)'
etc.....

Comment: @KristoferBeck Don't fix a problem by introducing another one. Ask about *that* instead of your attempted solution.

Comment: @KristoferBeck You must have done something other than just remove the `if` around the call. I've edited the answer to show what it should look like.